# How can I catch M-SEARCH request on Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This is my program to catch M-SEARCH request.

```
router['m-search']('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send('Got a M-SEARCH request\n');
});
```

This code can response for such request.

```
M-SEARCH / HTTP/1.1
```

but, can not for such request

```
M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1
```

So, What I've modified like this, but I could not find any changes on this situations.

```
router['m-search']('*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send('Got a M-SEARCH request\n');
});
```

How can I catch real M-SEARCH request on Express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express can't serve custom HTTP verbs, because nodejs under it has a hardcoded words in http parser module. https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.29/deps/http_parser/http_parser.h#L87-119

Also you can check this answer: [Serving non-standard HTTP method with ExpressJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318837/serving-non-standard-http-method-with-expressjs)

Comment: Thanks, (... but I cannot understand why Express team trying to implement UPnP method with such manner.)